# How to Restrict range datetimepicker in one month?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Developer's example on the [range](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers).

For example:

If the start date is 07/01/2016, the end date must be no more than 08.01.2016.

And when you change the end date will also change the start date of the limit also for one month.

If I remove one of the fields, for example, the end field, will have no limit in the start date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the example you linked, you can add few lines of code to get what you need:

```js
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
});

$("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  var limit = e.date;
  if( e.date ){
    limit = e.date.add(1, 'month');
  }
  $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(limit);
});

$("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
  var limit = e.date;
  if( e.date ){
    limit = e.date.subtract(1, 'month');
  }
  $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(limit);
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use moment to calculate new date limit (see [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [`substract`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)). As the [doc says](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange), `dp.change` event gets the new date as an argument and you'll get `false` if you reset the date input field. You will reset [`minDate` and `maxDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate) using `false` as parameter.